# Does QuickFIX set PreviouslyReported field itself?

Tags: quickfix

I'm using QuickFIX C++ engine in my project.
I send a **TradeCaptureReport** message to a counter party. There's a field named **PreviouslyReported** in this message.

I set this value to N in the message but when I check the message that was sent, I see that it is set to Y in the resulting message.

Does **QuickFIX** set this field itself ignoring the value that I set?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

It's defined as a boolean, so you must use:

`message.set(FIX::PreviouslyReported(false));`

instead.